# Can sperm fertilize an egg before reaching full maturity?

Tags: obstetrics, fertility, sperm, sperm-count

There seems to be many couples out there that have intercourse frequently and yet still manage to have a child. However, I found a number of articles that describe sperm maturity as taking at least three months, with the shortest period being 42 days:

[New Findings on Sperm Life Cycle Could Impact Fertility Treatments](https://www.ucsf.edu/news/2006/03/6621/new-findings-sperm-life-cycle-could-impact-fertility-treatments)

It seems that a male who has ejaculated a lot during the 42 days before reaching the ovulation window would stand little chance of impregnating their mate. Can immature sperm still fertilize an egg?

Answer (score 3):

Immature sperm are not motile, and thus cannot travel up the Fallopian tubes to cause fertilization. However, all of your sperm are not simultaneously on a 42 day cycle. You have millions of sperm, each at a different stage in the cycle. It is the ones that are fully mature and ready to go that you need to worry about. No substitute for using a condom if you aren't ready to have kids.